# Can direction of frictional force be opposite to velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity, navier-stokes

The frictional force in incompressible Navier-Stokes equation is given by
$$\vec F = \nu \nabla^2\vec v$$

Lets assume simple 1D-flow along $x$, where $v$ depends on $z$:

$$v_x = v(z)$$

Then the frictional force along $x$ would be the shearing force
$$F_x = \partial^2v/\partial z^2$$

I understand this mathematically. But since the second derivative can be positive, e.g. for

$$v(z) = 10 z^2+100$$

(just to put a particular example), the frictional force

$$F_x = +20$$

would be along $v$. Intuitively I would say, that friction must always in opposite direction to $v$.

On the other hand, by assuming
$$v(z) = 10  ln (z)$$

we get

$$F_x = -10/z^2$$

so in this case friction acts in opposite direction to velocity. This is what I would expect naïvely.

Ho to explain this surprising "paradox"?

Is the first flow scenario which yields force in $v$ direction somehow unphysical? It would mean that a parcel of air is accelerated instead of getting slower by friction.

However, if I assume the equation is correct, both cases must be possible.

Comment: Lots of damping forces have terms proportional to the negative of the velocity. Air resistance is one example

Comment: but here, depending on the sign of $\partial^2 v/\partial z^2$, the force can be positive or negative with regard to v. This is my "problem".

Comment: The friction force opposes the relative velocity between adjacent layers, not the velocity of a layer with respect to your coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the friction force exerted on a fluid surface, you need to calculate
$$\int_S(-\sigma_{ij}n_j)dS$$
where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the stress tensor, and $n_{j}$ is the unit vector along the outward normal.

As can be seen from the above discussion, forces on surfaces can be either positive or negative. However, you have two adjacent layers. Let's call them A and B. Then you should choose what you want. The friction force of A against B or B against A. And, as @mmesser pointed out, friction is always opposed to relative velocity.

As an example, see section 17 in "Fluid Mechanic" from Landau-Lifshitz course  (Vol 6), in particular equation (17.6).

Hope this helps.

Comment: sounds plausible now. So it is not a contradiction when an air parcel is accelerated in the first given example - right?

Comment: @MichaelW, Yes! Actually the force is either F_x=+20 or F_x=-20 in that example. For z>0, we have dv_x/dz=20z>0. Therefore at any constant z>0, the upper layer exerts F_x=+20 on the lower one and the latter exerts F_x=-20 on the upper one.